# How to create a transaction offline using javascript?

Tags: daemon, javascript, transfer, messagesigning

I saw a method for sending a transaction to a daemon, but can't find information on how to create and sign a tx using javascript. I can't use the wallet-cli/RPC etc.

Answer (score 2):

Creating and signing a Monero transaction in javascript *without* using the wallet RPC interface is far from trivial. You'd need to:

1. Have a way of scanning the blockchain to find outputs you own, which is a) infeasible without using a daemon and b) would be ridiculously slow in javascript even with the help of a daemon.
2. Have all the cryptography code available in javascript, of which there are various pieces scattered over a few different projects, its unlikely you'll find *everything* you'd need neatly in one project.
3. Create a javascript implementation of a Monero [transaction](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/441ed9f2fef6a43708c115191c51ca16930ce95b/src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_basic.h#L193) object (and all its sub objects/types).
4. Implement the serialization of #3 to its binary form.
5. Broadcast the binary data to the Monero network.

The daemon and wallet RPC interfaces offer the easiest way to interact with Monero from external code, whatever language one wishes to use.

As [@user36303](https://monero.stackexchange.com/users/22/user36303) [pointed out](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/11672/7493), the MyMonero team use a lot of javascript (much of which created from c++), and though they don't use the official wallet RPC interface, they do have their own custom backend and API. So if you are going to embark on the steps above, there will likely be some code of use to you in their [repositories](https://github.com/mymonero).

Using the wallet RPC is significantly simpler - a call to [transfer](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#transfer) (which can be done offline if the RPC is local).

Answer (score 1):

mymonero has javascript code to create transactions which you can reuse (some surgery needed). Some of it runs binary blobs compiled from C++ though, which may not be what you want. See https://mymonero.com/.

Comment: I tried use mymonero-core-js, but I saw only `SendFunds` method. Where I can find examples or where to look. Also, I tried use @xmr-core/xmr-transactions, but I can't find true values for arguments of `create_transaction` (or examples)

Comment: Did you look at the URL I posted ? It should have all the javascript code. I can't go there to get the exact links for you since it blocks Tor.

Comment: Are you sure that the transaction is created offline or without requests to mymonero API? I can use **only** daemon api.

Comment: I did not claim that no mymonero API requests are made. However, I am reasonably sure any that are made can be replaced by daemon calls, though I'm not sure how much work is needed. Basically you need outputs to use as inputs. Pretty much all the rest is likely all there in the javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

monero-javascript now supports this use case specifically.  See https://github.com/monero-ecosystem/monero-javascript/blob/master/docs/developer_guide/view_only_offline.md