# How to perform cold signing with JS?

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, cold-storage

How can I construct a transaction using a watch only wallet RPC and cold sign using any nodejs library? In the end, I have to send this to the blockchain using the daemon or watch only wallet RPC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the wallet RPC on your view only (hot) wallet, you can call [transfer](https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#transfer) with `get_tx_metadata: true` and `do_not_relay: true` which will yield an `unsigned_txset` in the response.

Then on the spend wallet RPC (your cold wallet), call [sign_transfer](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#sign_transfer), passing in the `unsigned_txset` from above, which will yield a `signed_txset` in the response.

Back on the view only (hot) wallet RPC, call [submit_transfer](https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#submit_transfer), passing the data from `signed_txset` above in the `tx_data_hex` parameter.

The linked methods all have examples of these steps using curl. The calls are just simple HTTP POST requests, so libraries are not really needed.

Comment: It's not solve my problem. I can't use cold wallet in my solution, I want to sign transaction in my nodejs application. In other words, the private spend key should not leave my code.

Comment: Doing this *without* the RPC is far from trivial and there is no javascript library that has all the code you would need. My [answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/11677/7493) to a previous question of yours applies.